# How to create matrix of all function-values for multivariate functions

Tags: r, function, normal-distribution

In R, I have two vectors X and Y of different lengths, say

```
         X=1:6
         Y=1:8
```

I would like to construct a matrix where each entry (i,j) correspond to (for some constant sigma):

```
  dnorm(xi,yj,sigma)
```

i.e I would like to construct a matrix m such that

```
      m= dnorm(1,1,sigma) dnorm(2,1,sigma) ... dnorm(6,1,sigma)
         dnorm(1,2,sigma) dnorm(2,2,sigma) ... dnorm(6,2,sigma)
         .                                                   .
         .                                                   .
         .                                                   . 
         dnorm(1,8,sigma) dnorm(2,8,sigma) ... dnorm(6,8,sigma)
```

What is the most time-efficient way of constructing this matrix? I suspect the *apply functions can be used in a smart-manner, but am not sure of how.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be vectorized:

```
matrix(dnorm(rep(X,each=length(Y)),rep(Y,length(X)),1),length(Y));
##              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
## [1,] 3.989423e-01 2.419707e-01 5.399097e-02 0.0044318484 0.0001338302 1.486720e-06
## [2,] 2.419707e-01 3.989423e-01 2.419707e-01 0.0539909665 0.0044318484 1.338302e-04
## [3,] 5.399097e-02 2.419707e-01 3.989423e-01 0.2419707245 0.0539909665 4.431848e-03
## [4,] 4.431848e-03 5.399097e-02 2.419707e-01 0.3989422804 0.2419707245 5.399097e-02
## [5,] 1.338302e-04 4.431848e-03 5.399097e-02 0.2419707245 0.3989422804 2.419707e-01
## [6,] 1.486720e-06 1.338302e-04 4.431848e-03 0.0539909665 0.2419707245 3.989423e-01
## [7,] 6.075883e-09 1.486720e-06 1.338302e-04 0.0044318484 0.0539909665 2.419707e-01
## [8,] 9.134720e-12 6.075883e-09 1.486720e-06 0.0001338302 0.0044318484 5.399097e-02
```

Notes:

- The key here is the use of [`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) to repeat each vector to the same length of `length(X)*length(Y)`. We must of course stagger the repeated values such that we get every combination of x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>j</sub>. To do this, we must use the `each` argument for one of the `rep()` calls and the `times` argument (the default with no explicit name) for the other.
- Calling [`dnorm()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) on the two repeated vectors (with the constant σ) results in a vector of the aforementioned length containing the required output values in linear form.
- We finally must build a matrix out of that vector with a call to [`matrix()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html). Since you indicated you want the columns to correspond to different `X` values and the rows to correspond to different `Y` values, we need `length(X)` columns and `length(Y)` rows, thus I've provided `length(Y)` for the `nrow` argument of `matrix()`, and it does the rest.
- We must be careful to ensure that we used the `each` and `times` arguments for the correct input vectors. To get this right we must know that, by default, `matrix()` effectively lays out the underlying vector *across rows* first and only then *across columns* (note: I use the word *across* as opposed to *along*, so when I say *across rows* you should visualize that as going downward *along* a column). This means we need to use `times` when repeating `Y` and `each` when repeating `X`.

---

Alternative based on [`expand.grid()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html) and [`with()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html):

```
matrix(with(expand.grid(Y=Y,X=X),dnorm(X,Y,1)),length(Y));
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! Really appreciate the notes.